# how to change react-mathjax-preview font size and font in REACT JS?

Tags: reactjs, size, font-size, mathjax, preview

I'm using  react-mathjax-preview package in my code:

```
<h5 style={{"text-align":"center" ,"text-overflow":"ellipsis"}}><MathJax math={"$$"+\lim_{x \to \infty} \exp(-x) = 0+"$$"}  /></h5>
```

Please guide me on this change the font size and font on 'react-mathjax-preview' node module

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the config prop supplied with react-mathjax-preview

i.e.

```
<MathJax 
  math={math} 
  config={{ "HTML-CSS": { fonts: [ "sana-Math"], scale: 400 } }} 
/>
```

you can find the all config object properties here https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/options/output-processors/HTML-CSS.html#configure-html-css

for size and font use the, **scale** and **fonts** definition as shown above

note that mathjax has limited fonts you can use

Comment: Thanks Mike for your valuable inputs